# Combining year, month, day columns into a single date column with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, datetime, dataframe

I keep running into an error when combining my data:

```
record_id   month   day year   sex
1              7    17  1977    M
2              7    15  1979    M
3              7    26  1978    F
4              7    16  1973    M
```

I tried different methods of combining the month, date and year into one column:

```
1. surveys_df['date'] = surveys_df['month'].astype(str) + surveys_df['day'] + surveys_df['year']
2. surveys_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(surveys_df[['month', 'day', 'year']])

3. r= pd.to_datetime(surveys_df[['year', 'month', 'day']])

4. surveys_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(surveys_df[['day','month','year']])
```

The error I get:

> ValueError: cannot assemble the datetimes: day is out of range for
>   day

I know I can force it by using **error= 'coerce'** but I will like to refrain from using that method.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df[['day','month','year']], dayfirst=True)` ? Not sure how `pd.to_datetime` works in python2.. maybe you have a very old version of pandas?

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful, In fact if you were able to provide such an example, the solution will likely become obvious.

Comment: @jpp So it isn't as much of a requirement that the OP provide a [mcve], I have marked this as a dupe of a better post.

Comment: Hi, what if it returned `KeyError: "['year'] not in index"`? Thanks

Answer (score 14):

```
pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day']])

0   1977-07-17
1   1979-07-15
2   1978-07-26
3   1973-07-16
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

If there are invalid combinations you want to NaTify, then add the `errors='coerce'` argument.